# Enable/Disable a button

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik

I have a button as follows:

```
RadButton lnkAdd = new RadButton();
lnkAdd.ID = "BtnAdd";
lnkAdd.CommandName = RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName;
lnkAdd.Text = "Add New Record";
lnkAdd.Style.Add("display", "none");
container.Controls.Add(lnkAdd);
```

I want to enable it on click of a row in the grid. I have the following JavaScript to do this:

```
function OnRowSelected(sender, args) {       
    var clientDataKeyName = args.get_tableView().get_clientDataKeyNames()[0];   
    var clientDataKeyValue = args.get_tableView().get_selectedItems()[0].getDataKeyValue(clientDataKeyName);     
    var grid = args.get_tableView(); 
    var linkButton1 = $telerik.findControl(grid.get_element(), "BtnAdd");  
    if (clientDataKeyValue == "Proposal") {
        linkButton1.set_enabled(false);
    }
    else
        linkButton1.set_enabled(true);
}
```

Though it reaches the `linkButton1.set_enabled(true)`, the button is not enabled. 
I also tried  the following to enable the button `linkButton1.style.display = "block";`
But this throws an error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'display' of undefined or null
>   reference.

Though it finds the button, style is rendered as undefined.

Comment: I know there is normally an issue that you need to reference there ClientId, if your ClientIDMode isn't set to static.

Comment: Don't use CLientIDMode=Static for complex controls like these :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only hidden the main wrapping element of the button via its display CSS property, you should use the same thing to show it again:

```
linkButton1.get_element().style.display="inline-block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Any UIControl (including RadioButtons) can be enabled and disabled using the [IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Basically, you can just set the button to

```
linkButton1.IsEnabled = false;
```

In order to disable the button and

```
linkButton1.IsEnabled = true;
```

to reenable it. Hope that helps.